# Factorization (Oxford MAT question) Help?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, quadratics

**Oxford MAT test, Q3, please help:**

Suppose that the equation:
$x^4 + Ax^2 + B = (x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b)$

holds for all values of $x$

***i.*** Find $A$ and $B$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

***ii.*** Use this information to find a factorization of the expression:

$x^4-20x^2+16$

as a product of two quadratics in $x$.

***iii.*** Show that the four solutions of the equation:

$x^4-20x^2+16=0$

can be written as $\pm\sqrt7$ $\pm\sqrt3$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this question?

Comment: No idea - something to do with completing the square?

Comment: multiply the quadratics by hand and see what you get.

Comment: @MichaelHarding Completing the square is what you do when you want to get rid of annoying cross-terms. In this example, the cross-terms are actually what we have information about, so that's not the way to go here.

Comment: @Yeldarbskich $x^4+2bx^2-a^2x^2+b^2$ now what?

Comment: @MichaelHarding: Now write as $x^4+(2b-a^2)x^2+b^2$, and identify the coefficient of $x^2$ with $A$, and the constant coefficient with $B$.

Comment: hint: rewrite $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b)$ as $(x^2+b+ax)(x^2+b-ax)$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply out the quadratics on the RHS $((x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b))$ and equate the corresponding coefficients:

i.e. equate the coefficients of $x^2$ to find an expression for $A$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

Similarly, equate the coefficients of $x^0$ to find an expression for B in terms of $a$ and $b$ (from the equation, $B= b^2$). 
The rest of the question should be straightforward from there.